# Composing Future List Akka Scala

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to collect a List of Future custom object from Akka actors, this is my code:

```
    var game_manager_backends: List[ActorRef] = List()

    implicit val ec = context.dispatcher
    val taskFutures: List[Future[Game]] = game_manager_backends map { gm_be =>
        implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
        val result = gm_be ? GameStatus
    }


    val searchFuture = Future sequence taskFutures

    searchFuture.onSuccess {
      case results: List[Game] => origin ! results
    }
```

This

```
game_manager_backends
```

is the List that contains all actor i want to ask a `Game` object, then i want collect all this `Game` Objects in a List and send back to the origin actor, with this implementation this is the error that give me on the `map` line:

```
type mismatch;  found   : List[Unit]  required: List[scala.concurrent.Future[common.Game]]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Remove `val result = ` or add another line with `result` stmt.

Comment: if I remove `val result =` this is the error: `type mismatch;  found   : List[scala.concurrent.Future[Any]]  required: List[scala.concurrent.Future[common.Game]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `val result = gm_be ? GameStatus` to `val result = (gm_be ? GameStatus).mapTo[Game]`. You also don't need it to be a `val`.

Comment: if i do this `(gm_be ? GameStatus).mapTo[Game]` without `val result =`works

Comment: I'm glad. Hopefully it helped.

Answer (score 0):

1. You get `Unit` cause do not return any value inside `map` (fix for this proposed above in comment).
2. `?` ask on akka returns `Future[Any]` but you want `Future[common.Game]` to fix this - extra mapping required.

`result map {
    case a@Game => a
  }`

Comment: can you please write my code above with your solution? because i haven't understand what you mean, thanks

Comment: see my comment in the other answer of @nattyddubbs